# ElasticSearch - Problems with edgeNGram tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I use ElasticSearch for indexing database. I'm trying to use edgeNGram tokenizer to cut strings to shoter ones with requirement "new string must be longer then 4 chars".
I use following code to create index:

```
PUT test
POST /test/_close

PUT /test/_settings
{
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
      "index_edge_ngram" : {
                "type": "custom",  
                "filter": ["custom_word_delimiter"],                
        "tokenizer" : "left_tokenizer"
      }         
    },
    "filter" : {
            "custom_word_delimiter" : {
                "type": "word_delimiter",
                "generate_word_parts": "true",
                "generate_number_parts": "true",
                "catenate_words": "false",
                "catenate_numbers": "false",
                "catenate_all": "false",
                "split_on_case_change": "false",
                "preserve_original": "false",
                "split_on_numerics": "true",
                "ignore_case": "true"
            }      
    },
    "tokenizer" : {
      "left_tokenizer" : {
        "max_gram" : 30,
        "min_gram" : 5,
        "type" : "edgeNGram"
      }
    }       
    } 
}

POST /test/_open
```

Now I run test to overview the results

```
GET /test/_analyze?analyzer=index_edge_ngram&text=please pay for multiple wins with only one payment
```

and get the results

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "pleas",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 5,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "p",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 8,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 5
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 6
      },
      {
         "token": "pa",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 9,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 7
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 8
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 9
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 10
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 11
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 12
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 13
      },
      {
         "token": "f",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 14
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 15
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 16
      },
      {
         "token": "fo",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 17
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 18
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 19
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 20
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 21
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 22
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 23
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 24
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 25
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 26
      },
      {
         "token": "m",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 16,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 27
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 28
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 29
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 30
      },
      {
         "token": "mu",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 17,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 31
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 32
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 33
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 34
      },
      {
         "token": "mul",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 18,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 35
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 36
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 37
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 38
      },
      {
         "token": "mult",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 19,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 39
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 40
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 41
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 42
      },
      {
         "token": "multi",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 20,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 43
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 44
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 45
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 46
      },
      {
         "token": "multip",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 21,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 47
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 48
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 49
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 50
      },
      {
         "token": "multipl",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 22,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 51
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 52
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 53
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 54
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 55
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 56
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 57
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 58
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 59
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 60
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 61
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 62
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 63
      },
      {
         "token": "w",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 25,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 64
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 65
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 66
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 67
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 68
      },
      {
         "token": "wi",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 26,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 69
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 70
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 71
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 72
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 73
      },
      {
         "token": "win",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 27,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 74
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 75
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 76
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 77
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 78
      },
      {
         "token": "wins",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 28,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 79
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 80
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 81
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 82
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 83
      },
      {
         "token": "wins",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 28,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 84
      },
      {
         "token": "please",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 85
      },
      {
         "token": "pay",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 86
      },
      {
         "token": "for",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 14,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 87
      },
      {
         "token": "multiple",
         "start_offset": 15,
         "end_offset": 23,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 88
      },
      {
         "token": "wins",
         "start_offset": 24,
         "end_offset": 28,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 89
      },
      {
         "token": "w",
         "start_offset": 29,
         "end_offset": 30,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 90
      }
   ]
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why there are tokens shoter then 5 characters?
2. Why "position" property shows position of the token, but not the position of the word in the text? Looks like the other tokenizers works in that way.
3. Why there are not all the words in the output? Looks like it stops on the "wins".
4. Why there are so many repeats of the same token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building custom analyzers, it's worth going step-by-step and checking what is generated by each step in the analysis chain:

1. first the tokenizer slices and dices your input into tokens
2. then tokens filters take the tokens from step 1 as input and do their thing
3. finally char filters are applied

In your case, if you check what comes out of the tokenizer phase, it goes like this. See we're just specifying the `tokenizer` (i.e. `left_tokenizer`) as parameter.

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9201/test/_analyze?tokenizer=left_tokenizer&pretty' -d 'please pay for multiple wins with only one payment'
```

The result is:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "pleas",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 5,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "please",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 6,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "please ",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "please p",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 4
  }, {
    "token" : "please pa",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 5
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 10,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 6
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay ",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 11,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 7
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay f",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 8
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay fo",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 13,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 9
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 10
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for ",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 15,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 11
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for m",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 16,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 12
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for mu",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 17,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 13
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for mul",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 18,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 14
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for mult",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 19,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 15
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multi",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 20,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 16
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multip",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 17
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multipl",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 22,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 18
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multiple",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 23,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 19
    "position" : 20
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multiple w",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 25,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 21
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multiple wi",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 26,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 22
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multiple win",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 27,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 23
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multiple wins",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 28,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 24
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multiple wins ",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 29,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 25
  }, {
    "token" : "please pay for multiple wins w",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 30,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 26
  } ]
}
```

Then, your token filters will take each of the tokens above and do their job. For instance,

- the first token `pleas` will come out as `pleas`
- the second token `please` as `please`
- the third token `please` (note the space at the end), as `please`
- the fourth token `please p` as the two tokens `please` and `p`
- the fifth token `please pa` as the two tokens `please` and `pa`
- etc

So, your `left_tokenizer` considers the whole sentence as a single token input and tokenizes it from 5 characters to 30, which is why it stops at `wins` (that answers question 3)

As you can see above, some tokens are repeated because the `word_delimiter` token filter treats each token from the tokenizer in isolation, hence the "duplicates" (that answers question 4) and the tokens shorter than 5 characters (that answers question 1)

I don't think this is the way you want it to work, but it's not clear from your question how you want it to work, i.e. the kind of searches you want to be able to do. All I'm offering here is an explanation of what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Perfest answer! You've opened my eyes. Can you help me with the second question?

Comment: Glad I could help. As for question 2, as you noticed, `position` is simply the position of the token within the list of tokens. However, `start_offset` and `end_offset` give you the position of that token within the input text.